# JQuery messes layout of web page

Tags: jquery

I had a working Spring Roo webapp, but it didn't have any jQuery in it.

Now I want to add some Ajax functionality, so I downloaded the jQuery .js file, and included it in my "head" section of my layout file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

Now, when I load the app up, all my resources have disappeared (images etc). The main pages all work ok, but they look really basic because the images/styles etc etc have gone.

I took a "view source" of the generated HTML page before and after adding the "script" element, and  they are identical (according to WinMerge). No errors in FireFox's error console either.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have another JS framework in your page, such as mootools or scriptaculous? There could be a conflict.

Comment: Yep, I had Dojo. I've added some more comments below Nicola's answer - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
$.noConflict();
//use only jQuery instead of $ from here
```

if your sites works ok after doing this you probably have another framework installed and this is conflicting with jQuery

Comment: Excellent tip, thanks. I put it in (within its own scrip  tag but otherwise the same as in your code sample) and it all works. I know Roo uses dijit/dojo (whatever it's called...) so there must be some kind of conflict as you said. If I figure out what it is I'll post it up. Cheers

Comment: This (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84064-jQuery-support-for-Roo) is a good description of the JQuery/Dojo situation with Roo. I think for now I'll stick with Dojo as it's configured OOB, and they're both good so it doesn't really matter which one I use.